# Does The Workplace support embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: support, formatting, markdown

[Over on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462), I am attempting to compile a complete list of Stack Exchange sites which support YouTube embedding.

Searching on The Workplace Meta, I was unable to find any discussion of whether embedded YouTube videos are supported. Because [YouTube embedding is not shown in the markdown preview window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299082/display-embedded-youtube-videos-in-markdown-preview), there's no way to test without posting publically.

**Are embedded YouTube videos supported on The Workplace?**

<sub>*Usually I would test this in a [site-specific formatting sandbox](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2824/48480), but The Workplace doesn't seem to have one.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

YouTube embedding isn't supported in The Workplace.  Even if it was, it would be a bad idea, as it is far too easy to sneak something that is NSFW, and a questionable youtube video embedded in a page could set off IT security sweeps.

Comment: I completely agree. YouTube embeds make sense for some communities, (Arqade, Movies & TV, Music Practice & Theory), but it wouldn't make much sense on the Workplace.

Comment: Agreed, this is a terrible idea for the Workplace.

Comment: May I suggest a slight rewording/reordering? "Youtube embedding is not supported on The Workplace. *newline* Even if it were, it would be a bad idea."

Answer (score -1):

There's only one way to find out.

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>